# Resizable treepanel in window in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, resize, treeview, autoresize

**I have a Treepanel:**

```
treepanel = Ext.define('filteredTree', {
                      extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
                      title: 'Filtered Tree',
                      store: store,
                      width: 784,
                      height: 550,
                      buttons: [
                       {
                           text: 'Select',
                           handler: function () {
                               var panel = this.up('treepanel');
                               //...selection of value
                           }
                       }
                    ]
    //...Here is search mechanism

    });
```

**and the window in which it's displayed. The window is resizable:**

```
        win = Ext.create('widget.window', {
            title: 'Выбор значения из словаря',
            header: {
                titlePosition: 2,
                titleAlign: 'center'
            },
            closable: true,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            maximizable: true,
            width: 800,
            minWidth: 350,
            height: 600,
            tools: [{ type: 'pin' }],
            theme:"classic",
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: 5
            },
            items: [
                 Ext.create('filteredTree')
            ]
        });
```

**I'd like to see if the window size changes the size of the panel also changes. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the layout of the window to **fit**.

Panel will occupy the complete space inside the window and resizes accordingly.You can remove height and width from the tree panel.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Выбор значения из словаря',
            header: {
                titlePosition: 2,
                titleAlign: 'center'
            },
            closable: true,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            maximizable: true,
            width: 600,
            minWidth: 350,
            height: 400,

            layout:'fit',
            items: [
                {xtype:'treepanel',
                 padding:5,
                      title: 'Filtered Tree',                 
                      buttons: [
                       {
                           text: 'Select',
                           handler: function () {
                               var panel = this.up('treepanel');

                           }
                       }
                    ]}  
            ]
        }).show();
```

Comment: Thank you, Saloo! That what I want!